# Selenium, how to verify if element exist

Tags: python, selenium

web pages could either has element with **id=container_53201** or **id= container_24206**, but not both. I tried to verify each page has which of the element. but the following code caused the error:

> No such element [id= container_24206]

if the web page has the other element. Please advise how to fix this issue.

```
if driver.find_element_by_id('container_53201'):
        print('Single Match') 
elif driver.find_element_by_id('container_24206'):
        print('multiple Match') 
else:
        print('Could not find')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `find_element_by_*` you should use `find_elements_by_*`.
`find_element_by_*` method throws exception in case of no element found while `find_elements_by_*` will always return a **list** of matching elements. So, in case of matches it will return a non-empty list interpreted by python as Boolean True, while in case of no matches it will return an empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean False.
So, this code should work better:

```py
if driver.find_elements_by_id('container_53201'):
        print('Single Match') 
elif driver.find_elements_by_id('container_24206'):
        print('multiple Match') 
else:
        print('Could not find')
```

Also you would probably better use the modern syntax: instead of `find_elements_by_id` using `find_elements(By.ID, **)`
With it your code will look as following:

```py
if driver.find_elements(By.ID,'container_53201'):
        print('Single Match') 
elif driver.find_elements(By.ID,'container_24206'):
        print('multiple Match') 
else:
        print('Could not find')
```